# Blocking when invoking SSL_Read

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, centos

The current OpenSSL version is 1.1.1d.
I am using SSL to TCP Socket.
Below are the related sources.

```
...
...
    
struct  timeval tv;
fd_set  fdIn;

tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 10000;

FD_ZERO(&fdIn);

if ( SocketId > 0 ) {
    FD_SET( SocketId, &fdIn );
}

int retVal {0}, nflag {0};

while((retVal = select(FD_SETSIZE, &fdIn, nullptr, nullptr, &tv)) == -1
  && (errno == EINTR)) {
    .. TODO

}

if ( SocketId > 0 && FD_ISSET( SocketId, &fdIn ) ) {
    // This...
    int s = SSL_read(pSSL, pbuf, size);
}

...
...
```

The source is functioning as expected.

However, problems have occurred since 1.1.1g was compiled and used.
Invoking the method SSL_Read causes blocking for a few seconds.

OpenSSL Library compiled.
Do I need to specify additional options when compiling?
PS.Tested in CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

> Invoking the method SSL_Read causes blocking for a few seconds.

That's not uncommon. In general `SSL_read` and `SSL_write` can not be used with `select` in the same way as a normal `read` and `write` can be. This was already the case with previous OpenSSL versions but there are more cases with TLS 1.3 session handling now with OpenSSL 1.1.1 because tickets are send after the TLS handshake is done.

In general `SSL_read` and `SSL_write` need to be used together with a non-blocking socket and the result need to be checked regarding `SSL_WANT_READ` and `SSL_WANT_WRITE` - and need to be acted on based in these "errors". This is because a SSL read might require a write internally and a SSL write might require a read internally. Additionally `SSL_pending` need to be used in addition to `select` since it might be that data from a previous SSL frame are still left unread in the local SSL object and `select` just cares about the socket but not internal buffers.

Comment: See [OpenSSL and select()](http://www.past5.com/tutorials/2014/02/21/openssl-and-select/) for a more detailed explanation and example.